# How to send/receive layer 2 frames on wlan

Tags: c, sockets, networking, unix, pcap

*What I wanna do:* Implement a layer 2 protocol in user-space.

So I'm using pcap under Linux 2.6.32 to sniff packets:

```
    ...
    struct pcap_t *pcap_h = pcap_open_live("wlan0", BUFSIZ, 1, 0, errbuf);
    ...
    while (1) { 
          int ret = pcap_loop(pcap_h, -1, newpkt_callback, NULL);
          ...
    }
    ...
```

Which works just fine for all packets. But, when I use pcap to send packets with no ether_head and no IP header:

```
    const char pkt[] = "WHATEVER";
    nsent = pcap_sendpacket(pcap_h, (const u_char *)pkt, len);
    ...
```

I can only sniff the packet on the localhost, and not on other laptops that are running the same program.  So the question is "how can I broadcast messages without ether_head on a wlan"?  Any pointers would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You can't do this if you are using an access point (infrastructure mode), as the access point relays the frames between other wireless stations and thus must know how to talk your layer 2 protocol.

I suggest implementing your protocol at layer 3 (and you may want to look into `PF_PACKET` sockets).

Comment: I did actually try it using raw sockets and PF_PACKET,  but the problem still exists. As for the AP, the whole point of the protocol is to not use an access point. In other words, I'm looking for a way to simply inject data into the wireless device and receive them on the other end.

Comment: @Peyman: Are you actually associating the cards in ad-hoc mode, though?  Additionally, some wireless cards simply do not support promiscuous mode.

Comment: I did try ad-hoc mode too. And for the promiscuous mode, isn't the `pcap_open_live` supposed to return at a warning?

Comment: @Peyman: In my tests, promiscuous mode was apparently successful but simply had no effect on the cards in question.  (I still don't see any reason that you can't use the standard layer 2 protocol - perhaps using the layer 2 all-stations address on all frames - with a custom layer 3 protocol to achieve the same result).

Answer (score 0):

You have to send complete frame with it's headers, not just some random data.
Take a look at this manual http://linux.die.net/man/3/pcap at function pcap_inject(). In creating new frame this could help http://www.tcpdump.org/pcap.html, or just use libnet library http://libnet.sourceforge.net/libnet.html.